# hadoop.dll, winutils.exe and multiiple applications built on hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, anaconda, file-permissions

On downloading Spark on Windows 10 OS and properly setting up all environments and system variables I got a code execution error that stated "null/bin/winutils.exe does not exist". I fixed the issue by downloading winutils.exe, but want to understand why downloading winutils.exe fixed the issue.

Before installing Spark I had Anaconda installed on my machine, which I understand was the root of the issue (given having multiple applications built on Hadoop can cause the error if only one permissions library exists on local memory). Why can't multiple applications function with the same file permissions library? What's the machinery going on behind the scenes here?

Answer (score 0):

wunutils allows for Hadoop's UNIX permissions model to be mapped to the Windows OS.

Anaconda doesn't need any such functionality if you're just reading from the local filesystem rather than HDFS

> error that stated "null/bin/winutils.exe does not exist".

The fact that null was in the output suggests something was setup incorrectly

Comment: Hm, so would this mean that Spark can't function on any Windows OS without winutils.exe? I'm in a course that uses Spark and some of the other students using the same OS didn't need the winutils.exe binary. Given setup was consistent across Windows users (w/ exception of whatever students already had on local memory on their respective machine), Thanks.

Comment: When I search "Spark Windows 10", I end up with this, which says to download WinUtils - https://www.ics.uci.edu/~shantas/Install_Spark_on_Windows10.pdf